# LoadError when 'require'-ing Twitter gem on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, rubygems, twitter-gem

I'm using Rails 4.0.1, Ruby 2.0, and running Windows.
I tried 'require'-ing 'twitter' in one of my controller files:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'
class MyController < ApplicationController
  #etc
```

I added 'twitter' to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter'
```

And then restarted my rails server. However, when I ran `rails s` I got:

```
c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.5.3-x86-mingw32/lib/ruby_http_parser.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.0/ruby_http_parser (LoadError)
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.5.3-x86-mingw32/lib/ruby_http_parser.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.5.3-x86-mingw32/lib/http_parser.rb:2:in `require'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.5.3-x86-mingw32/lib/http_parser.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.5.3-x86-mingw32/lib/http/parser.rb:1:in `require'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.5.3-x86-mingw32/lib/http/parser.rb:1:in `<top (require d)>'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter/streaming/connection.rb:1:in `require'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter/streaming/connection.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter/streaming/client.rb:4:in `require'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter/streaming/client.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from c:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter.rb:26:in `require'
#etc
```

I've tried researching this error but haven't found anything the usual reason for such an error has been forgetting to have twitter in the Gemfile or forgetting to require rubygems. Any help for a  novice rails dev? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter/streaming/connection.rb

Comment Line no:1.

It shall fix the issue.